# zone.js:2935 GET http://localhost:49923/api/Empleados/Empleados 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, .net-core

estoy ejecutando un crud con `.netcore` y `angular` ,la cual compila  pero no envia los datos  a la base de datos y me muestra el siguiente error error:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET
> /api/Empleados/Empleados</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"
> headers: HttpHeaders
> lazyInit: ƒ ()
> lazyUpdate: null
> normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
> __proto__: Object
> message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:49923/api/Empleados/Empleados: 404 Not Found"
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"
> ok: false
> status: 404
> statusText: "Not Found"
> url: "http://localhost:49923/api/Empleados/Empleados"
> __proto__: HttpResponseBase
> ```

Comment: Ese error es bastante claro, el endpoint no existe. No sé mucho de .net pero deberías revisar donde declaró sus rutas. Posiblemente sea un error de tipeo.

Comment: este  es el codigo  componen.ts                                      
    constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject("BASE_URL") baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<Empleados[]>(baseUrl + 
     "api/Empleados/Empleados").subscribe(result => {
      this.lstEmpleados = result;
    }, error => console.error(error))
  }
  }